# Graphically, how does the non-linear activation function project the input onto the classification space?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks

I am finding a very hard time to visualize how the activation function actually manages to classify non-linearly separable training data sets.

Why does the activation function (e.g tanh function) **work** for non-linear cases? 
What exactly happens mathematically when the activation function projects the input to output? What separates training samples of different classes, and how does this work if one had to plot this process graphically?

I've tried looking for numerous sources, but what exactly makes the activation function actually **work** for classifying training samples in a neural network, I just cannot grasp easily and would like to be able to picture this in my mind.

Comment: This is a pretty cool [blog post](https://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/) (not mine) discussing the sort of thing you seem to be interested in.